# Why were all tag badges unawarded and then awarded again?

Tags: bug, estado-completado, medallas

I just noticed that the [Badges page](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/badges) shows that many were just awarded to Diego:

> [image]

If I check [his profile](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/5481/diego?tab=badges&sort=recent) it shows a very long list of recently awarded tag badges. While I am very happy for him (I would award all of them to him :-D), I think that he already had many of them, probably all of them.

I browsed through the [Bronze tag badges page](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze) and found out that it is happening to other users as well:

- [Charlie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/12637/charlie?tab=badges&sort=recent)
- [leonbloy](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/61/leonbloy?tab=badges&sort=recent)
- [aparente001](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/9385/aparente001?tab=badges&sort=recent)
- [Walter Mitty](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/900/walter-mitty?tab=badges&sort=recent)?

Why is this happening? I don't see any pattern other than the two main users of the site plus a few random.

Comment: Same issue reported on [Math.Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33051/228959)

Comment: Not only the bronze tag medals, but also the silver tag medals. And I suppose it would have been the same for the gold medals, if any would have been awarded so far. I was surprised when I saw all those medals [being suddenly re-awarded to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf9IR.png). I tried to look for information in Meta.SE but I did not find anything.

Comment: Update: [Glorfindel just asked about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/359973/350184) on Meta.SE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be resolved. Lots more details on what happened and why are available [on this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/360040/164200).